# How to determine tty number

Tags: java, linux

I have an USB device which works as a virtual serial port. I want to get it working on Linux. When the device was attached, Linux usb-to-serial drivers and tty drivers find it, and device node **/dev/ttyUSBx** appears. Several identical devices can be attached to the system. I write Java code, which will have to communicate with devices via **RXTX library**.

So I want to know, which device corresponds to the particular tty node. How can I get this information in Java? I think that I have to create JNI with necessary functionality, but I don't understand actions chain of C code. Can anyone help to find the way?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute shell commands directly from Java.

```
String[] command = new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "find /sys/devices -name ttyUSB0 | grep -v 'tty/tty'";
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(child.getInputStream()));
String line = input.readLine();
...
```

This way you get details of device node connection in USB tree. For example you get:

```
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/ttyUSB0
```

Then get serial number of device by executing

```
cat /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/serial
```

to uniqely identify specific device by its serial number like `ftE2MLXP`